# Java store every date of a year in array

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to create ArrayLists of every year and I want each date in that year saved in the corresponding ArrayList. How would I be able to do that? It is possible with Calendar?

EDIT:

So now I have this, anyone knows why it only prints 2013/12/31 and not all the dates of that year?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int current = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
ArrayList<String> current_year = getDatesOfYear(current);
```

The method:

```
private ArrayList<String> getDatesOfYear(int year){
    ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year+1,0,0);
    while(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)==year){
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        String date = df.format(cal.getTime());
        dates.add(date);
        System.out.println(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return dates;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible with Calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT:

*Answer to your [EDIT] (I don't have 50 reputation to write comments directly under your message)*

Setting day value to zero actually means (current date - 1 day). if you think about it actually makes sense, because there can be no day 0 in any given month.

This works as expected:

```
    cal.set(year,0,1);
```

Unfortunately, javadoc for Calendar.set() method doesn't contain any info about this case. But we can run a couple of tests to prove this:

```
    cal.set(2013, 1, 0); // 2013-FEB-01 - (1 DAY) = 2013-JAN-31
    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); // 2013
    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); // 0 = JAN
    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // 31

    cal.set(2010, 0, 0); // 2010-JAN-01 - (1 DAY) = 2009-DEC-31
    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); // 2009
    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); // 11 = DEC
    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // 31
```

So your code actually works. Just need to set day to `1` instead of `0`.

I hope this helps!

---

#### previous answer:

This should work. I added some comments to help understanding the code. This is not the most efficient way to accomplish this but it's quite readable. Dates for each year are stored as Strings but you could modify the code to store Calendar instances instead (probably not a very good idea, because its inefficient).

```
    Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> data = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year_from = 2000;
    int year_to = 2010;

    for (int year = year_from; year <= year_to; year++) {
        // make sure an array list for a given year is present
        if(! data.containsKey(year)) {
            data.put(year, new ArrayList<String>());
        }

        ArrayList<String> dates = data.get(year);

        for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1); // since 0 = January
            int maxDaysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);

            for (int day = 1; day <= maxDaysInMonth; day++) {
                // format date in such a way, that month and days are padded with zeroes up to 2 digits
                String dateAsString = String.format("%d-%02d-%02d", year, month, day);
                dates.add(dateAsString);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(data.keySet()); // list of years present
    System.out.println(data.get(2003)); // last day of Feb: 28th
    System.out.println(data.get(2004)); // last day of Feb: 29th
```

Console output:

```
    /* OUTPUT:
     * 
    [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010]
    [2003-01-01, 2003-01-02, 2003-01-03, 2003-01-04, 2003-01-05, 2003-01-06, 2003-01-07, 2003-01-08, 2003-01-09, 2003-01-10, 2003-01-11, 2003-01-12, 2003-01-13, 2003-01-14, 2003-01-15, 2003-01-16, 2003-01-17, 2003-01-18, 2003-01-19, 2003-01-20, 2003-01-21, 2003-01-22, 2003-01-23, 2003-01-24, 2003-01-25, 2003-01-26, 2003-01-27, 2003-01-28, 2003-01-29, 2003-01-30, 2003-01-31, 2003-02-01, 2003-02-02, 2003-02-03, 2003-02-04, 2003-02-05, 2003-02-06, 2003-02-07, 2003-02-08, 2003-02-09, 2003-02-10, 2003-02-11, 2003-02-12, 2003-02-13, 2003-02-14, 2003-02-15, 2003-02-16, 2003-02-17, 2003-02-18, 2003-02-19, 2003-02-20, 2003-02-21, 2003-02-22, 2003-02-23, 2003-02-24, 2003-02-25, 2003-02-26, 2003-02-27, 2003-02-28, 2003-03-01, 2003-03-02, 2003-03-03, 2003-03-04, 2003-03-05, 2003-03-06, 2003-03-07, 2003-03-08, 2003-03-09, 2003-03-10, 2003-03-11, 2003-03-12, 2003-03-13, 2003-03-14, 2003-03-15, 2003-03-16, 2003-03-17, 2003-03-18, 2003-03-19, 2003-03-20, 2003-03-21, 2003-03-22, 2003-03-23, 2003-03-24, 2003-03-25, 2003-03-26, 2003-03-27, 2003-03-28, 2003-03-29, 2003-03-30, 2003-03-31, 2003-04-01, 2003-04-02, 2003-04-03, 2003-04-04, 2003-04-05, 2003-04-06, 2003-04-07, 2003-04-08, 2003-04-09, 2003-04-10, 2003-04-11, 2003-04-12, 2003-04-13, 2003-04-14, 2003-04-15, 2003-04-16, 2003-04-17, 2003-04-18, 2003-04-19, 2003-04-20, 2003-04-21, 2003-04-22, 2003-04-23, 2003-04-24, 2003-04-25, 2003-04-26, 2003-04-27, 2003-04-28, 2003-04-29, 2003-04-30, 2003-05-01, 2003-05-02, 2003-05-03, 2003-05-04, 2003-05-05, 2003-05-06, 2003-05-07, 2003-05-08, 2003-05-09, 2003-05-10, 2003-05-11, 2003-05-12, 2003-05-13, 2003-05-14, 2003-05-15, 2003-05-16, 2003-05-17, 2003-05-18, 2003-05-19, 2003-05-20, 2003-05-21, 2003-05-22, 2003-05-23, 2003-05-24, 2003-05-25, 2003-05-26, 2003-05-27, 2003-05-28, 2003-05-29, 2003-05-30, 2003-05-31, 2003-06-01, 2003-06-02, 2003-06-03, 2003-06-04, 2003-06-05, 2003-06-06, 2003-06-07, 2003-06-08, 2003-06-09, 2003-06-10, 2003-06-11, 2003-06-12, 2003-06-13, 2003-06-14, 2003-06-15, 2003-06-16, 2003-06-17, 2003-06-18, 2003-06-19, 2003-06-20, 2003-06-21, 2003-06-22, 2003-06-23, 2003-06-24, 2003-06-25, 2003-06-26, 2003-06-27, 2003-06-28, 2003-06-29, 2003-06-30, 2003-07-01, 2003-07-02, 2003-07-03, 2003-07-04, 2003-07-05, 2003-07-06, 2003-07-07, 2003-07-08, 2003-07-09, 2003-07-10, 2003-07-11, 2003-07-12, 2003-07-13, 2003-07-14, 2003-07-15, 2003-07-16, 2003-07-17, 2003-07-18, 2003-07-19, 2003-07-20, 2003-07-21, 2003-07-22, 2003-07-23, 2003-07-24, 2003-07-25, 2003-07-26, 2003-07-27, 2003-07-28, 2003-07-29, 2003-07-30, 2003-07-31, 2003-08-01, 2003-08-02, 2003-08-03, 2003-08-04, 2003-08-05, 2003-08-06, 2003-08-07, 2003-08-08, 2003-08-09, 2003-08-10, 2003-08-11, 2003-08-12, 2003-08-13, 2003-08-14, 2003-08-15, 2003-08-16, 2003-08-17, 2003-08-18, 2003-08-19, 2003-08-20, 2003-08-21, 2003-08-22, 2003-08-23, 2003-08-24, 2003-08-25, 2003-08-26, 2003-08-27, 2003-08-28, 2003-08-29, 2003-08-30, 2003-08-31, 2003-09-01, 2003-09-02, 2003-09-03, 2003-09-04, 2003-09-05, 2003-09-06, 2003-09-07, 2003-09-08, 2003-09-09, 2003-09-10, 2003-09-11, 2003-09-12, 2003-09-13, 2003-09-14, 2003-09-15, 2003-09-16, 2003-09-17, 2003-09-18, 2003-09-19, 2003-09-20, 2003-09-21, 2003-09-22, 2003-09-23, 2003-09-24, 2003-09-25, 2003-09-26, 2003-09-27, 2003-09-28, 2003-09-29, 2003-09-30, 2003-10-01, 2003-10-02, 2003-10-03, 2003-10-04, 2003-10-05, 2003-10-06, 2003-10-07, 2003-10-08, 2003-10-09, 2003-10-10, 2003-10-11, 2003-10-12, 2003-10-13, 2003-10-14, 2003-10-15, 2003-10-16, 2003-10-17, 2003-10-18, 2003-10-19, 2003-10-20, 2003-10-21, 2003-10-22, 2003-10-23, 2003-10-24, 2003-10-25, 2003-10-26, 2003-10-27, 2003-10-28, 2003-10-29, 2003-10-30, 2003-10-31, 2003-11-01, 2003-11-02, 2003-11-03, 2003-11-04, 2003-11-05, 2003-11-06, 2003-11-07, 2003-11-08, 2003-11-09, 2003-11-10, 2003-11-11, 2003-11-12, 2003-11-13, 2003-11-14, 2003-11-15, 2003-11-16, 2003-11-17, 2003-11-18, 2003-11-19, 2003-11-20, 2003-11-21, 2003-11-22, 2003-11-23, 2003-11-24, 2003-11-25, 2003-11-26, 2003-11-27, 2003-11-28, 2003-11-29, 2003-11-30, 2003-12-01, 2003-12-02, 2003-12-03, 2003-12-04, 2003-12-05, 2003-12-06, 2003-12-07, 2003-12-08, 2003-12-09, 2003-12-10, 2003-12-11, 2003-12-12, 2003-12-13, 2003-12-14, 2003-12-15, 2003-12-16, 2003-12-17, 2003-12-18, 2003-12-19, 2003-12-20, 2003-12-21, 2003-12-22, 2003-12-23, 2003-12-24, 2003-12-25, 2003-12-26, 2003-12-27, 2003-12-28, 2003-12-29, 2003-12-30, 2003-12-31]
    [2004-01-01, 2004-01-02, 2004-01-03, 2004-01-04, 2004-01-05, 2004-01-06, 2004-01-07, 2004-01-08, 2004-01-09, 2004-01-10, 2004-01-11, 2004-01-12, 2004-01-13, 2004-01-14, 2004-01-15, 2004-01-16, 2004-01-17, 2004-01-18, 2004-01-19, 2004-01-20, 2004-01-21, 2004-01-22, 2004-01-23, 2004-01-24, 2004-01-25, 2004-01-26, 2004-01-27, 2004-01-28, 2004-01-29, 2004-01-30, 2004-01-31, 2004-02-01, 2004-02-02, 2004-02-03, 2004-02-04, 2004-02-05, 2004-02-06, 2004-02-07, 2004-02-08, 2004-02-09, 2004-02-10, 2004-02-11, 2004-02-12, 2004-02-13, 2004-02-14, 2004-02-15, 2004-02-16, 2004-02-17, 2004-02-18, 2004-02-19, 2004-02-20, 2004-02-21, 2004-02-22, 2004-02-23, 2004-02-24, 2004-02-25, 2004-02-26, 2004-02-27, 2004-02-28, 2004-02-29, 2004-03-01, 2004-03-02, 2004-03-03, 2004-03-04, 2004-03-05, 2004-03-06, 2004-03-07, 2004-03-08, 2004-03-09, 2004-03-10, 2004-03-11, 2004-03-12, 2004-03-13, 2004-03-14, 2004-03-15, 2004-03-16, 2004-03-17, 2004-03-18, 2004-03-19, 2004-03-20, 2004-03-21, 2004-03-22, 2004-03-23, 2004-03-24, 2004-03-25, 2004-03-26, 2004-03-27, 2004-03-28, 2004-03-29, 2004-03-30, 2004-03-31, 2004-04-01, 2004-04-02, 2004-04-03, 2004-04-04, 2004-04-05, 2004-04-06, 2004-04-07, 2004-04-08, 2004-04-09, 2004-04-10, 2004-04-11, 2004-04-12, 2004-04-13, 2004-04-14, 2004-04-15, 2004-04-16, 2004-04-17, 2004-04-18, 2004-04-19, 2004-04-20, 2004-04-21, 2004-04-22, 2004-04-23, 2004-04-24, 2004-04-25, 2004-04-26, 2004-04-27, 2004-04-28, 2004-04-29, 2004-04-30, 2004-05-01, 2004-05-02, 2004-05-03, 2004-05-04, 2004-05-05, 2004-05-06, 2004-05-07, 2004-05-08, 2004-05-09, 2004-05-10, 2004-05-11, 2004-05-12, 2004-05-13, 2004-05-14, 2004-05-15, 2004-05-16, 2004-05-17, 2004-05-18, 2004-05-19, 2004-05-20, 2004-05-21, 2004-05-22, 2004-05-23, 2004-05-24, 2004-05-25, 2004-05-26, 2004-05-27, 2004-05-28, 2004-05-29, 2004-05-30, 2004-05-31, 2004-06-01, 2004-06-02, 2004-06-03, 2004-06-04, 2004-06-05, 2004-06-06, 2004-06-07, 2004-06-08, 2004-06-09, 2004-06-10, 2004-06-11, 2004-06-12, 2004-06-13, 2004-06-14, 2004-06-15, 2004-06-16, 2004-06-17, 2004-06-18, 2004-06-19, 2004-06-20, 2004-06-21, 2004-06-22, 2004-06-23, 2004-06-24, 2004-06-25, 2004-06-26, 2004-06-27, 2004-06-28, 2004-06-29, 2004-06-30, 2004-07-01, 2004-07-02, 2004-07-03, 2004-07-04, 2004-07-05, 2004-07-06, 2004-07-07, 2004-07-08, 2004-07-09, 2004-07-10, 2004-07-11, 2004-07-12, 2004-07-13, 2004-07-14, 2004-07-15, 2004-07-16, 2004-07-17, 2004-07-18, 2004-07-19, 2004-07-20, 2004-07-21, 2004-07-22, 2004-07-23, 2004-07-24, 2004-07-25, 2004-07-26, 2004-07-27, 2004-07-28, 2004-07-29, 2004-07-30, 2004-07-31, 2004-08-01, 2004-08-02, 2004-08-03, 2004-08-04, 2004-08-05, 2004-08-06, 2004-08-07, 2004-08-08, 2004-08-09, 2004-08-10, 2004-08-11, 2004-08-12, 2004-08-13, 2004-08-14, 2004-08-15, 2004-08-16, 2004-08-17, 2004-08-18, 2004-08-19, 2004-08-20, 2004-08-21, 2004-08-22, 2004-08-23, 2004-08-24, 2004-08-25, 2004-08-26, 2004-08-27, 2004-08-28, 2004-08-29, 2004-08-30, 2004-08-31, 2004-09-01, 2004-09-02, 2004-09-03, 2004-09-04, 2004-09-05, 2004-09-06, 2004-09-07, 2004-09-08, 2004-09-09, 2004-09-10, 2004-09-11, 2004-09-12, 2004-09-13, 2004-09-14, 2004-09-15, 2004-09-16, 2004-09-17, 2004-09-18, 2004-09-19, 2004-09-20, 2004-09-21, 2004-09-22, 2004-09-23, 2004-09-24, 2004-09-25, 2004-09-26, 2004-09-27, 2004-09-28, 2004-09-29, 2004-09-30, 2004-10-01, 2004-10-02, 2004-10-03, 2004-10-04, 2004-10-05, 2004-10-06, 2004-10-07, 2004-10-08, 2004-10-09, 2004-10-10, 2004-10-11, 2004-10-12, 2004-10-13, 2004-10-14, 2004-10-15, 2004-10-16, 2004-10-17, 2004-10-18, 2004-10-19, 2004-10-20, 2004-10-21, 2004-10-22, 2004-10-23, 2004-10-24, 2004-10-25, 2004-10-26, 2004-10-27, 2004-10-28, 2004-10-29, 2004-10-30, 2004-10-31, 2004-11-01, 2004-11-02, 2004-11-03, 2004-11-04, 2004-11-05, 2004-11-06, 2004-11-07, 2004-11-08, 2004-11-09, 2004-11-10, 2004-11-11, 2004-11-12, 2004-11-13, 2004-11-14, 2004-11-15, 2004-11-16, 2004-11-17, 2004-11-18, 2004-11-19, 2004-11-20, 2004-11-21, 2004-11-22, 2004-11-23, 2004-11-24, 2004-11-25, 2004-11-26, 2004-11-27, 2004-11-28, 2004-11-29, 2004-11-30, 2004-12-01, 2004-12-02, 2004-12-03, 2004-12-04, 2004-12-05, 2004-12-06, 2004-12-07, 2004-12-08, 2004-12-09, 2004-12-10, 2004-12-11, 2004-12-12, 2004-12-13, 2004-12-14, 2004-12-15, 2004-12-16, 2004-12-17, 2004-12-18, 2004-12-19, 2004-12-20, 2004-12-21, 2004-12-22, 2004-12-23, 2004-12-24, 2004-12-25, 2004-12-26, 2004-12-27, 2004-12-28, 2004-12-29, 2004-12-30, 2004-12-31]
     *
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straightforward - all you need is a way to add days (which yes, you do get with Calendar).

Thinking about it, you know that the first day in every year is January 1st, and you know that days proceed monotonically through the year.  So in pseudocode:

```
date = Jan 1st $year
while (date.year == $year)
    result.add(date)
    date = addOneDay(date)
```